# Excluir hostname de um nome de computador via REGEX

Tags: regex

NOMEDOSERVIDOR.DOMINIO.COM.BR

Deste formato acima quero retirar o NOMEDOSERVIDOR. via regex

Ficando somente DOMINIO.COM.BR

Qual seria a expressão regular(REGEX) que varia isto?

Comment: Depende, quais são as regras que você quer incluir nessa expressão? Você quer pegar tudo que está após o primeiro ponto? O domínio pode incluir `www.` também, de forma que você tenha que considerar esse ponto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^.*?\.` usa essa Regex Deve resolver...
`^`: pra indicar que é no começo de uma string
`.*`: Excluir tudo...
`?\.`: Até o primeiro Ponto.